# append an numpy ndarray to another one along certain dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

There exist two `numpy.ndarray`, e.g., `A` is of shape `(5,3,2)`, `B` is of shape `(5,3)`.

```
A = np.random.rand(5,3,2)
B=np.random.rand(5,3)  #----- there was typo here
```

I would like to append B into A, and make the resulting array `C` with shape `(5,3,3)` I tried to use `np.contaenate`,  but it does not work.

```
c=np.concatenate((a,b),axis=2)
```

Comment: What was the error?  Do you have any ideas of how to correct it?  "it does not work" is not enough!

Comment: You can use `reshape`: `np.concatenate((np.arange(30).reshape(5, 3, 2), np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3, 1)), axis=2)`

Comment: that is first do B = B.reshape(5,3,1) than concatenate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(5,3,2)
b = np.random.rand(5,3)

b = b[..., np.newaxis] # or np.expand_dims(b, axis=2) or b.reshape(b.shape+(1,))
print(b) # (5, 3, 1)
c = np.append(a, b, axis=2)
print(c.shape) # (5, 3, 2)
```